# Lifetime of pdf disk

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

The pdf for the lifetime X, in years, of a Superstuff disk drive is given as follows:

$f(x) =
\begin{cases} 2/x^2 &  \text{for } x\geq2\text{ }  \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$.

> (i) Determine the cdf, $F(x)$ for all $x$ values.

My attempt:

$F(x_0)$ $=$ $ \int_{-\infty}^{2} 0dx +2 \int_{2}^{x_0} x^{-2} dx$

$=$ $1-(2/x_0)$

Answer:

$F(x)$ $=$ $0$ for $x<2$

$F(x)$ $=$ $(-2/x) + 1$ for $x\geq 2$

> (ii) Find the probability $P(3\leq X \leq 4)$

$P(3<x<4)=$ $\int_{3}^{4}f(x) dx=2\int_{3}^{4}x^{-2}dx$

Answer:

$1/6$

> (iii) Determine $x_1$ such that $P(X<x_1)=2/3$ (Here $x_1$ is the $66.7$th percentile)

I am not sure about this one. Can someone please show me how to do this with the working?

> (iv) Out of a set of $10$ randomly selected Superstuff disk drives, what is the probability that at least $4$ will last longer than $5$ years?

$P(X\geq 5$ $=$ $\int_{5}^{\infty} 2/x^{2}dx$

$=$ $2/5$

$P(X\geq 4)= 1-P(X<4)=$

$=$ $1-$${10\choose 3}(2/5)^3(3/5)^7 + {10\choose 2}(2/5)^2(3/5)^8 + {10 \choose 1}(2/5)^1(3/5)^9 + {10 \choose 0}(2/5)^0(3/5)^{10}\;$

Answer:

$=$ $.6178$

Is this correct? If so, is there another way of doing this problem? I am not sure about (iii). Can someone please help me with this and the working as well?

Comment: By your correct answer to an earlier question, the required number is the number $x_0$ such that $1-\frac{2}{x_0}=\frac{2}{3}$. Solve for $x_0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is $x_1$ $=$ $6$?

Comment: Yes, the $66.6\dots$ percentile  is $6$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If anything is unclear, please do not hesitate to write.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was looking at your profile and saw how many times you helped people and gave answers to their questions. You explained it well too. I learned lots of things from your explanations. I might ask you to help me on other questions if you are around at the time. I plan to go ahead in some topics and would like to see some of the proofs or working to some parts of certain questions if that is ok. Thanks again.